# Graphic showing the money travelling clockwise

Tags: betting-position

It's said in poker that 'money travels clockwise', from early position toward the button. Has anyone ever constructed a graphic from live data showing this occurring? I'm sure there are stats showing the button winning more than UTG, but would be great to see this in some graphical way. Anyone ever tagged 1 chip and seen where it moved?!

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen such a thing done with a real world chip, nor any sort of online analysis.

However I believe, it could be possible to create this type of graphic if you could get access to a high volume, winning, online poker player's Poker Tracker 4 or Holdem Manager 3 databases.

A pro player would have millions of accumulated hand histories. Inside those databases you could mine the positional data for each seat and then figure out some way to represent it graphically.

I would love to see such a thing actually.

Answer (score -1):

Not an answer that covers the question, but I have 100,000 Omaha hands stored in pokertracker, most of them at low tables playing drunk and it looks like the blinds blind my poker.

Surprisingly, as I have played those games really bad, I have profits from button and cutoff position.

Note position is more important in Omaha than in Holdem. I won money even drunk.

[image]